# Deploy Django to Heroku (TemplateDoesNotExist)

Tags: python, django

I just deploy the project to Heroku, however the templates can't be found. Can someone help me out

settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'Users/jay/Downloads/PJ/ecommerce/templates') ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Error message:

Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:
list.html
Exception Location: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py in get_template, line 19
Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.8
Python Path:
['/app/.heroku/python/bin',
 '/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python36.zip',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 22 Aug 2019 09:51:24 +0000
Template-loader postmortem

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /app/Users/jay/Downloads/PJ/ecommerce/templates/list.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/list.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/list.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/crispy_forms/templates/list.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /app/accounts/templates/list.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /app/carts/templates/list.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /app/orders/templates/list.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bootstrap4/templates/list.html (Source does not exist)

Comment: show us your directory structure and tell us where your template is located. This is wrong: `os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'Users/jay/Downloads/PJ/ecommerce/templates')` (look at what it became: ***/app/Users/jay/Downloads/PJ/ecommerce/templates/list.html (Source does not exist)***)

Comment: i got it now thxs